# When the user enters the letter n as the major mark, the major mark will instead be represented by the number:

Tags: c++

My code goes like this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string z,zz ="";
    int x,y;
    cin >> x >> y >> z >> zz;
    for (int a = 1; a <= x; ++a) {
        cout << z;
      for (int b = 1; b <= y; ++b) {
         cout << zz;
      }
   }
   cout << z;
   return 0;
}
```

If my input is
3 9 n a

It should print out
0aaaaaaaaa1aaaaaaaaa2aaaaaaaaa3

But my code prints out
naaaaaaaaanaaaaaaaaanaaaaaaaaan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you:

- Move the declaration of `a` outside of the outer `for` loop.
- Change both `cout << z;` statements to `cout << a;`.
- Change the outer `for` loop to start at 0 instead of 1, and to use `<` insted of `<=`.

Then you will get the output you want.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string z, zz;
    int x, y;
    cin >> x >> y >> z >> zz;
    int a;
    for (a = 0; a < x; ++a) {
        cout << a;
        for (int b = 1; b <= y; ++b) {
            cout << zz;
        }
   }
   cout << a;
   return 0;
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/j7jREa)

Note that in this case, `z` becomes redundant and can be eliminated if you can remove `n` from your input.

Comment: or keep `a` in loop and print `x` after the loop.